# I am facing problem in deserializing my json

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, pojo

Every time I am trying to convert my Json to POJO I am getting this error

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 371 path $.x-business-use-case-usage[0]
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
> at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
> at com.google.gson.Gso

My json file is

```html
{
  "x-fb-trace-id": [
    "VFJHSFvswhd"
  ],
  "x-fb-request-id": [
    "GVMShgvwjmfmsnvhjgs"
  ],
  "null": [
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  ],
  "Alt-Svc": [
    "h3-29=\":443\"; ma=3600,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=3600"
  ],
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": [
    "*"
  ],
  "x-fb-rlafr": [
    "0"
  ],
  "Connection": [
    "Keep-Alive"
  ],
  "x-fb-rev": [
    "16746598"
  ],
  "Pragma": [
    "no-cache"
  ],
  "Date": [
    "Thu, 29 Jul 2019 13:41:17 GMT"
  ],
  "x-business-use-case-usage": [
    "{\"692950841314120\":[{\"type\":\"ads_management\",\"call_count\":3,\"total_cputime\":1,\"total_time\":5,\"estimated_time_to_regain_access\":0}]}"
  ],
  "Strict-Transport-Security": [
    "dbjkabjbfbkvj"
  ],
  "Cache-Control": [
    "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
  ],
  "Vary": [
    "Origin"
  ],
  "Expires": [
    "wkdfbvdksjwfbkjfkdb"
  ],
  "Content-Length": [
    "104"
  ],
  "X-FB-Debug": [
    "hdljwbejkfbkwejbkwjebkwjbfkwjfbejkfeifhwjkfbwejkfwbkjfebkf"
  ],
  "facebook-api-version": [
    "v10.0"
  ],
  "Content-Type": [
    "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  ]
}
```

And my POJO Structure is

```html
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class JsonClass {
    @SerializedName("x-business-use-case-usage")
    private List<UseCase> businessUseCase;
    

}
```

```html
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class UseCase {
    @SerializedName("692950841314120")
    private List<Case> c;
    
}
```

```html
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Case {
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("call_count")
    private Integer callCount;
    @SerializedName("total_cputime")
    private Integer totalCputime;
    @SerializedName("total_time")
    private Integer totalTime;
    @SerializedName("estimated_time_to_regain_access")
    private Integer estimatedTimeToRegainAccess;
}
```

I tried using this code but I am getting above error at the last line where I am trying to convert the json in POJO using gson.

```html
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("res.json"));
        JsonObject s = (JsonObject)obj;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonClass header = (JsonClass) gson.fromJson(s.toString(), JsonClass.class);
```

Comment: Why are you using a Json parser to read the file, then converting the resulting JsonObject to a String, and parsing that with Gson?

Comment: Also, the problem is `List<UseCase> businessUseCase`. In the Json, that is actually a `String` not a list, hence the error.

Comment: I know there are simpler ways but this code is written while I was trying to make it work anyhow :)

Comment: So, Cannot convert it directly to POJO without any String manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 "x-business-use-case-usage": [
    "{\"692950841314120\":[{\"type\":\"ads_management\",\"call_count\":3,\"total_cputime\":1,\"total_time\":5,\"estimated_time_to_regain_access\":0}]}"
  ],
```

here, as you can see, `x-business-use-case-usage` is an `string[]` with 1 element - which happens to be another encoded, escaped json string.

Your pojo, expects it to be an `List<UseCase>` so it will not work as actual json will map to `List<String>`.

This is what error says, that object is expected (actually `{`) but `string` is given. You have to parse it as string and then parse it again as `UseCase`

To make it work in single run you can try to write custom deserializer that will remove escaping and then parse nested json. Refer to GSON docs on how to make custom deserializers.